# How to find darkest pixel using php?

Tags: php, image, pixel

How can i find in my image the darkest pixel, which occurence in image is maximal? So to find darkest pixel which i can see more than other pixels.
Here i'm founding on my image noise, and color it with white color, but how to find darkest pixel? I try to find in rgb array element witch occurence is maximal, but so i found white pixel to. Here is part of my code:

```
<?php

    function components($color) {
      return array(($color >> 16) & 0xFF, ($color >> 8) & 0xFF, $color & 0xFF);
    }

    // Performs "similarity test" of 2 colors
    function isSimilar($color1, $color2) {
      $c1 = components($color1);
      $c2 = components($color2);
      for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $k = ($c1[$i] > $c2[$i]) ? ($c1[$i] - $c2[$i]) / $c2[$i] : ($c2[$i] - $c1[$i]) / $c1[$i];
        if ($k > 0.35) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    function LoadJpeg($imgname)
    {
        $count = 0;
        /* Attempt to open */
        $im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
        $imagedata = getimagesize($imgname);

        $n = $imagedata[0];
        $m = $imagedata[1];
        for($i=0; $i<$imagedata[0]; $i++){
            for($j=0; $j<$imagedata[1]; $j++){
                $rgb[$i][$j] = imagecolorat($im, $i, $j);
                //echo $rgb[$i][$j];
                //echo "<br>";
            }
        }



    /*    for ($k = 0; $k < $n; $k++)
        {
            for ($l = 0; $l < $m; $l++)
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
                {
                    for ($j = 0; $j < $m; $j++)
                    {
                        if (($i+1 == $n) && ($j+1 == $m))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ($j+1 == $m and $rgb[$i][$j] > $rgb[$i+1][0])
                            {
                                $t = $rgb[$i][$j];
                                $rgb[$i][$j] = $rgb[$i+1][0];
                                $rgb[$i+1][0] = $t;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if ($rgb[$i][$j] > $rgb[$i][$j+1])
                                {
                                    $t = $rgb[$i][$j];
                                    $rgb[$i][$j] = $rgb[$i][$j+1];
                                    $rgb[$i][$j+1] = $t;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/



        for($i=0; $i<$imagedata[0]-3; $i++){
            for($j=0; $j<$imagedata[1]-3; $j++){
                if (isSimilar($rgb[$i][$j], $rgb[$i][$j + 3]) or isSimilar($rgb[$i][$j], $rgb[$i + 3][$j])) 
                {
                    #echo "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa";
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    //echo "<br> <br>";
                    //echo $count;
                    //$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

                    imagesetpixel($im, $i, $j, 16777215);
                    cropCentered($im,20,20);
                }                  

            }
        }

        return $im;
    }

    function cropCentered($img, $w, $h)
    {
      $cx = $img->getWidth() / 2;
      $cy = $img->getHeight() / 2;
      $x = $cx - $w / 2;
      $y = $cy - $h / 2;
      if ($x < 0) $x = 0;
      if ($y < 0) $y = 0;
      return $img->crop(0, 0, $w, $h);
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    $img = LoadJpeg('1.png');




    imagejpeg($img,null, 100);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a color model different than RGB - in this case HSL is useful, because it contains "Lightness" component. Based on this component we can judge whether some color is lighter or darker than another. There are several methods of converting RGB to HSL, I've used the one described in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space#Lightness) (see HSL "bi-hexcone" model):

```
<?php

// Returns whether c2 is darker than c1
function isDarker($c1, $c2) {
  // Find L (lightness) component in a HSL model
  $max1 = max($c1);
  $min1 = min($c1);
  $l1 = ($max1 + $min1) / 2;
  $max2 = max($c2);
  $min2 = min($c2);
  $l2 = ($max2 + $min2) / 2;

  // Compare colors based on L component (lower means darker)
  return $l2 < $l1;
}

// Assuming colors are stored in a 2-dimensional $rgb array
$rowCount = count($rgb);
$colCount = count($rgb[0]);
$darkest = $rgb[0][0];
for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < $colCount; $j++) {
    if (isDarker($darkest, $rgb[$i][$j])) {
      $darkest = $rgb[$i][$j];
      // Optionally you can save the indices $i and $j
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is set a variable that will store the darkest color.

You then loop through each pixel testing if that pixel is darker than the darkest color (stored in that darkest color variable).

If the pixel is darker, you set it equal to the darkest color.

This way, the darkest color will only/always be overwritten by a darker color if there is one.

```
$pixels = array(/*put colors that correspond to pixels here*/)
$darkest = $pixels[0];
for($i=0; $i<$count($pixels); $i++){
    if($pixels[$i] is darker than $darkest){ //you will have to figure out how to do that part
        $darkest = $pixels[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to check if i is more darker than i+1

Comment: You mean how do you write that in code?... If you do mean that, the point of this forum, but I will give you a general idea

Comment: you will use something like that.

Comment: but rgb - value in dec is si that more value = more darkest color?